# Ember.Select binding sets to undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have got an Ember.Select in my template. The options are populated from content I get from a server. All the options are rendered fine. But when I want to show the selected value it will set the attribute to undefined.

Template:

```
{#with this as context}}
  {{#each}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{view Ember.Select content=context.types optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.name' value=type}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

Controller:

```
types: function() {
    return this.store.find('myType');
}.property()
```

Model I'm looping through:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  type: DS.attr() // <= this is the selected type (id)
});
```

MyType model:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
});
```

This code will render all the options in the select element. Like so:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">My first type</option>
  <option value="2">My second type</option>
</select>
```

The following things I don't understand:

- When I inspect my data (ember inspect add-on) the property type is set to undefined.
- But when I select an option the type property is set with the right id.
- When I remove the `value=type` the type attributes have the correct value when I inspect the data.

jsbin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/3/edit

Comment: Can you put together a bin showing the issue: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: added the jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 2 problems:

1. Your select content was bounded to an unfulfilled Ember-Data promise (which is an odd creature by itself). You can bypass that by if-ing on the isFulfilled property.
2. The IDs for such a model are strings, not integers.

look [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/33/edit) for the fixes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This does solve the problem. Do you know why it is that when I change the attribute type of the model Stuff into: `type: DS.belongsTo('type')`. It does not work anymore? see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/39/edit

Comment: Nevermind the DS.belongsTo issue. I forgot to add type.id in the value attribute of select.

Answer (score 1):

Using a model promise in controller is antipattern. Route's model and afterModel hook wait until a Promise is resolved and fulfilled. So all your data from store and from json API gonna be properly downloaded and setup when your controller and your template rendering.

The "Ember Way" solution is to setup both model in current Route's setupController hook, so you don't have to use a hack in your template.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugetoxoyira/44/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      stuffs: this.store.find('stuff'),
      types: this.store.find('type')
    }); 
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('types', model.types);        
    controller.set('model', model.stuffs); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is having a promise in the controller an anitpattern? With your answer I would have problems using the view with a render helper.

Comment: In Route, model and afterModel always wait until a promise resolved. On controller, you have to use then to manage them. But if you have only one or two main model in your route section, the 'Ember Way' is to manage them in Route instead of Controller. Could you please show an example, where would you have problems in the view?

Comment: The problem is you can't reuse your view like this because you get the types in the model hook. When you use the render helper you can pass in a model. For example an other list of 'Stuff'. But when you do that, the types property in the controller is not defined. Maybe the better solution here is to create a new view for the available types instead of putting it in the controller. This view would be responsible to get all available types.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. In this case a view or component could help... I try to figure out a more general and reusable solution and post it later. (It's already after midnight on this side of the world. :-)